# How do i put a label

Tags: java, label

I cannot understand where should i put the label 'one' in the code (I need to skip the while infinite loop)

```
one:
while (true) {
    x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert a data");
    y = y + Integer.parseInt(x);

    if (x == "ok") {
    break one;
    }
}

//here is where i need to get using the label
System.out.println("I did break");
```

Can anyone explain me where should i put the label?

Comment: Unrelated problem: Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i actually found the answer myself:
The error is that when trying to assign to y the value of an int, if it gets a string ('ok') it terminates with an error.
So i just needed to move that line after the if sequence (and use the equals method) and it now works.

```
one:
while (true) {
    x = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert a data");

    if (x.equals("ok")) {
    break one;
    }

    y = y + Integer.parseInt(x);
}

//here is where i need to get using the label
System.out.println("I did break");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a do while loop.

```
do{
 x =JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Insert a data");
y = y + Integer.parseInt(x);
}while(!(x.equals("ok")));

//here is where i need to get using the label
System.out.println("I did break");
```

Comment: yes you're right but i wanted to understand how to use labels. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the label is already at the right place.

According to the [Oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html):

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not
>   transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred
>   to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated)
>   statement.

In your example you do not even need the label, because the your break statement will exit the `while(true)` loop anyway. Normally you use labels when you have nested loops.

Comment: I thought the same, but why it doesn't work then? The program actually terminates when it gets to the break